# How use import async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, import, asyncstorage

I made a `Storage.js` file with some Utils function. In most case, I use it in this way:

```
async someFunction()=>{ let foo = await getOnDevice(someName)}
```

But the in my case, I have a problem with the syntax

```js
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'

export const saveOnDevice = async (name, data) => {
 try {
  if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
   await  AsyncStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(data));
  }
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
 }
};

export const getOnDevice = async (name) => {
 try {
  const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(name);
  if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
   return data
  }
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
 }
};
```

How can I use it without declaring an `async` function?

```js
import {saveOnDevice} from '../../utils/Storage'
export  function fetchUrlWithRedux(url) {
 return (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchUrlRequest(url));
  return fetchUrl(url, dispatch).then(([response, json]) => {
   if (response.status === 200) {
    saveOnDevice('url', json.data.host);
    dispatch(fetchUrlSuccess(json))
   }
   else {
    dispatch(fetchUrlError())
   }
  }).catch(() => dispatch(fetchUrlError()))
 }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `async/await` in your main file then you can use promise, like below.

```
saveOnDevice('url', json.data.host).then(() => {
  dispatch(fetchUrlSuccess(json))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `async` before the anonymous function passed to `.then()`, and `await` before the call to `saveOnDevice()`:

```
import {saveOnDevice} from '../../utils/Storage'
export  function fetchUrlWithRedux(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchUrlRequest(url));
        return fetchUrl(url, dispatch).then(async ([response, json]) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                await saveOnDevice('url', json.data.host);
                dispatch(fetchUrlSuccess(json))
            }
            else {
                dispatch(fetchUrlError())
            }
        }).catch(() => dispatch(fetchUrlError()))
    }
}
```